# What are the numbers on the end of lines in a stacktrace

Tags: windows, stack-trace

What do the the numbers after the "+" at the end of the lines in a stack trace represent?

```
Function   Source 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet    
ntdll!ZwRemoveIoCompletion+c    
kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+29    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+33    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+24    
w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread+39    
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

here they are 
+c
+29
+33
+24
+39 +34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are offsets, in hexadecimal, from the start of the named subroutine. For example

```
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

is 52 (34 hex) bytes into the routine BaseThreadStart in the kernel32 module.

Answer (score 3):

Offset inside the function. Eg. on frame 3 the return address is: the address of the kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatus symbol + 29 bytes.